# how to replace specific string from a json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a JSON object in which I am having a RAW SQL query with a parameter inside it. I am getting the value of the parameter from my HTML DOM element. HOW to replace it can any one tell me?
thanks

EG:-

```
[1,2,"select * from animal where animal = @value"]
```

i want to replace @value

Comment: in which environment do you need the replacement?

Comment: So will it be single `where` condition always?

Comment: @NinaScholz i want to replace in jquery

Comment: @GuruprasadRao yes

Answer (score 3):

If thats a string you can always use regex.

```
let jsonValue = [1,2,"select * from animal where animal = @value"]
jsonValue[2] = jsonValue[2].replace(/@value/, 'tiger'); // output select * from animal where animal = tiger
```

Comment: yes sure, you can replace the @value with whatever you want, instead of using tiger you can use "tiger"

Comment: i am getting actual value like "[[1,2,"select * from animal where animal = @value"]]" . Now i need to replace @value with some parameter.

Comment: yes of course, replace is not replacing the actual value but returning a new string. Take a look to the new code

Comment: @nicowernli i am working on offline system it is showing cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Comment: Well that means that jsonValue[2] does not exist. I've use the number 2 because was the index in the example you posted, but you should use the corresponding index of the string you want to change

Answer (score 1):

If you include the Lodash library in you project you can use this method, otherwise you need to use the traditional javascript replace method.

```
_.replace(array[2], '@value', 'my new value');
```